# Simple jQuery function onchange

Tags: jquery

this is a very simple question, but i have just started using jQuery for the fist time...

The question: why does this function not trigger?

```
$('#compare').mergely('get', 'rhs').on('change', function() {
      alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: it's a script using codemirror, what matters is that $('#compare').mergely('get', 'rhs') outputs a text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons your code doesn't work.
First, from your example, it appears your is triggered before [DOM Ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637725/what-is-dom-ready-event).
To fix that, surround all the code needed to be executed in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // All of your code goes here.

});
```

Lastly, it appears you're trying to use `onchange` event where it's not possible. Reading the manual of [Mergely](http://www.mergely.com/doc/index.html) one can easily see you can't bind events directly using the `on` method. Instead you may be able to do that using `cmsettings` which stand for [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_value) settings. Going though their API, I saw you can attach events such as `change` and `beforeChange`.

I guess that should do what you need, though I've never used those plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the #compare doesnt have an onchage to be fire, i saw the mergely plugin and it looks like your binding it to an div. So thats why it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery API for `.on('change',handler)`:

The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Other than the element not being one of those types, I suspect that the `mergely` call is returning something other than a jQuery object, which won't work with that function.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Although you are correct on how `on(change)` works, one could easily `simulate` a `change` event by simply using `trigger('eventName')` and the author of the plugin may have done that.