# javascript and jsquery working only from console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, console

There are no errors when i do **resize()** into console with this code, and the the box resizes it's height to it's width.

```
function resize() {
    let box = document.getElementById("id");
    let width = $("#id").width();
    box.style.height = width;
}
```

I want to do that automatically so i just tried adding **resize();** in the end of the js file like this:

```
function resize() {
    let box = document.getElementById("id");
    let width = $("#id").width();
    box.style.height = width;
}

resize();
```

But nothing happens and there is an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at resize (main.js:4)
    at main.js:7
resize @ main.js:4
(anonymous) @ main.js:7
```

Comment: Perhaps the JavaScript executes before the [DOM is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637750/924299).

Comment: Tried wrapping the function call into a **setInterval** of 10 seconds, there was the same error in console even before the 10 seconds.

Comment: For more info, doing **resize()** in console works fine, but also prints **undefined**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to encapsulate your function call in a ready function, since the elements are probably not yet loaded.

```
$(function() {
    resize();
});
```